# Google App Engine flex CORS configuration

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx, google-cloud-platform, cross-domain

I have a site (A) hosted in **App Engine** that needs to be accessed by proxy_pass by another site (B) hosted somewhere else.

Previously this site (A) was hosted in Kubernetes and the ingress configuration looked like this, and it worked perfectly:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: webapp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-webapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: webapp
          servicePort: 80
  - host: www.remote-server.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: webapp
          servicePort: 80
```

This way, by adding www.remote-server.com to the list of hosts, then www.remote-server.com was allowed to render my-webapp.com through a nginx proxy_pass.

Now my question is **how do we configure the same thing in App Engine flexible environment (nodejs runtime)?** Currently this what we get if we try this in App Engine without any special configuration:

[image]

That is because a remote server (in that case it's localhost for testing), is not allowed to proxy to the App Engine service (That's my assumption anyway).

For reference, this is the nginx configuration I'm using locally for testing this:

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /path/to/folder/;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /shopping {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass https://url-to-my-appengine-app.appspot.com;
        proxy_redirect default;
    }
}
```

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the [underlying Docker image](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docker) for the Node.js runtime on App Engine flexible environment uses NGINX as the web server so you're likely pursuing a path that won't work when you deploy even if you get it to work locally.

I believe to enable CORS support in your situation, you are going to have to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header within your application's code rather than within a configuration file.

Comment: Are you sure? When I ssh into the App Engine instance and run **docker ps**, I do see an nginx-proxy container sitting there. It might be acting as a reverse proxy on top of my Node.js web app.

Comment: I'm not totally sure, I based it off searching the image repo code. If I look at the PHP image, I do see nginx in the image repo, but not for Node.js.

That said, the answer likely could still be that it needs to be handled in the code.

Comment: The dockerfile list just npm start as its start command rather than something that looks to be running nginx: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docker/blob/master/runtime-image/Dockerfile

Comment: Actually you were right, it does work just by configuring this header within our Application. Thanks for the tip!